# ImportError: /usr/lib/libboost_python.so.1.54.0: undefined symbol: PyClass_Type

Tags: c++, python, boost, boost-python, archlinux

I have code written in C++:

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>

char const* greet()
{
  return "Yay!";
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(libtest)
{
  using namespace boost::python;
  def("greet", greet);
}
```

Now i want to import this dynamic library to python by:

```
import libtest
```

But I get:

```
ImportError: /usr/lib/libboost_python.so.1.54.0: undefined symbol: PyClass_Type
```

What should I do? My OS is Arch Linux.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, I have found solution for this problem. The simplest options is to compile by:

```
g++ testing.cpp -I/usr/include/python3.3m -I/usr/include/boost -lboost_python3 -lpython3.3m -o testing.so -shared -fPIC
```

Previously I used -lboost_python instead of -lboost_python3 ... But this solution is not cross platform so we can achieve this by cmake:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)


find_package(Boost 1.54 EXACT REQUIRED COMPONENTS python3)

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS} "/usr/include/python3.3m/" )
find_package(PythonLibs)
ADD_LIBRARY(testing SHARED testing.cpp)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(testing ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${PythonLibs_LIBRARIES})
```

Of course "/usr/include/python3.3m" won't be path to pythons include directory in all linux distros.

Comment: I think that you can use ${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS} instead of "/usr/include/python3.3m/". Is defined here https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindPythonLibs.html and it seems to work for me...

Comment: Yep, that would be better :)

Comment: Just wanted to point out that on my Arch Linux system it is `PYTHON_LIBRARIES` not `PythonLibs_LIBRARIES`. See: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindPythonLibs.html In case someone had a similar problem and still got undefined symbols.

Answer (score 2):

Use the same version of Python when building both Boost.Python and the `libtest` module, as well as when importing `libtest`.

`PyClass_Type` is is part of the Python 2 C API and not part of the Python 3 C API.  Hence, the Boost.Python library was likely built against Python 2.  However, it is being loaded by a Python 3 interpreter, where the `PyClass_Type` is not available.

Comment: So I tried to import libtest in Python 2 and I got: ImportError: ./libtest.so: undefined symbol: _ZN5boost6python6detail11init_moduleER11PyModuleDefPFvvE

Comment: @Yuras: That symbol is because `libtest` is compiled against Python 3, but being loaded by Python 2.  Just wanted to stress that one has to use the same version of Python when building both Boost.Python and the `libtest` module, as well as when importing `libtest`.