# Exposing C++ to Python error from BoostPython

Tags: python, c++, boost

I'm exposing a simple C++ code to Python through BoostPython library:

```
#include <boost/python/detail/wrap_python.hpp>
#include <boost/python.hpp>

using namespace boost::python;

bool test_api( void ){
   return true;
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(materials) {

   def( "test_api", test_api );

}
```

After I try to import this module, the python interpreter returns the error:

```
ImportError: ./example.so: undefined symbol: _Py_RefTotal
```

I've linked the module statically against the boost python library and the python dynamic libraries libpython3.2m.so and libpython3.2m.so.1.0 are present in the work directory.

Any suggestions on where to find the missing symbol?

Comment: try include `#include <boost/python/module.hpp>` You need this include for module definition.

Comment: No go.  It is still missing the symbol.  I noticed that the symbols is undefined in both libboost_python.a and libboost_python.so

Comment: Here is something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19894643/2050745

Comment: That looks promising... I don't have the python3 boost library.  I'm going to recompile boost make sure boost is consistent with my python installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Boost libraries were not consistent with the Python installation.

```
cd boost_source
./bootstrap.sh --with-libraries=python --prefix=../boost_target
```

To configure Boost to point to the correct Python installation:

```
vim tools/build/v2/user-config.jam
```

Edit the line that points to the Python:

```
using python : version_number
             : path_to_python_executable 
             : path_to_python_include_directory 
             : path_to_python_library_directory
```

Then, run the build system:

```
./b2
```

Answer (score 0):

_Py_RefTotal is defined in object.h under a precompiler guard:

```
$less include/python3.6m/object.h
```

```
#ifdef Py_REF_DEBUG
PyAPI_DATA(Py_ssize_t) _Py_RefTotal;
...
...
#endif /* Py_REF_DEBUG */
```

I was linking `python3.6m` but including headers from `include/python3.6dm`. Fixed issue including ptyhon3.6m