# libboost_python3.so.1.56.0: undefined symbol: PyClass_Type

Tags: c++, python-3.x, boost, cmake, boost-python

I'm trying to create a helloWorld module for Python 3 in C++ using the boost::python library.

Here is a `CmakeList.txt`:

```
set(Python_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS 3.4)
find_package( PythonLibs 3.4 REQUIRED )
include_directories( ${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS} )

find_package( Boost 1.56.0 EXACT COMPONENTS python3 REQUIRED )
include_directories( ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR} )

# Define the wrapper library that wraps our library
add_library( hello SHARED main.cpp )
target_link_libraries( hello ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${PythonLibs_LIBRARIES} )

# don't prepend wrapper library name with lib
set_target_properties( hello PROPERTIES PREFIX "" OUTPUT_NAME hello)
```

main.cpp

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>

char const* greet( )
{
    return "Hello world";
}    
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(mymodule)
{
    using namespace boost::python;
    def( "greet", greet );
}
```

I installed boost libraries from the source described [here](https://coderwall.com/p/0atfug), but it does not allow me to use the boost-python3 library (have an error in Cmake). For this purpose I used

```
./bootstrap.sh --with-python-version=3.4 --prefix=/usr/local
```

instead of

```
./bootstrap.sh --prefix=/usr/local
```

to explicitly specify version of python;

As an output, we get a shared library `hello.so`. All seems to be ok. But...

When I try to import the library to python script `script.py` with content:

```
import hello
```

in terminal using command *...$ python3 script.py*

I receive an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 1, in <module>
    import hello 
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/libboost_python3.so.1.56.0: undefined symbol: PyClass_Type
```

The question is: How to make the boost library compatible with Python 3? There are no problems with `python2`. But I need `python3`.
I also saw the [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19865757/importerror-usr-lib-libboost-python-so-1-54-0-undefined-symbol-pyclass-type/19894643#19894643) when the same error happens but it didn't help me.

My software:

- boost version 1.56.0
- Python 3.4
- cmake version 2.8.12.2
- gcc  4.8.2
- OS: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, 64 bit

Comment: Shouldn't `${PythonLibs_LIBRARIES}` be [`${PYTHON_LIBRARIES}`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindPythonLibs.html)?

Comment: Error is the same after I replaced `${PythonLibs_LIBRARIES}` into `${PYTHON_LIBRARIES}`

Comment: Have you tried the solution mentioned here ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19865757/importerror-usr-lib-libboost-python-so-1-54-0-undefined-symbol-pyclass-type

Comment: Yes, I did. (See the last 2 sentences, and link attached to the word [page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19865757/importerror-usr-lib-libboost-python-so-1-54-0-undefined-symbol-pyclass-type/19894643#19894643))

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As noted in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19870624/1053968):

> `PyClass_Type` is is part of the Python 2 C API and not part of the Python 3 C API. Hence, the Boost.Python library was likely built against Python 2. However, it is being loaded by a Python 3 interpreter, where the `PyClass_Type` is not available.

The exact procedure used to produce `libboost_python3.so` is not presented, so I can only speculate a non clean build, such as building Boost.Python with Python2, then reconfiguring bootstrap with Python3, and then building Boost.Python with the Python2 object files.  Regardless, verify a *clean* build of Boost.Python with Python3.

```bash
$ ./bootstrap.sh --with-python=/usr/bin/python2
...
Detecting Python version... 2.7
$ ./b2 --with-python --buildid=2 # produces libboost_python-2.so
$ ./bootstrap.sh --with-python=/usr/bin/python3 --with-python-root=/usr
...
Detecting Python version... 3.3
$ ./b2 --with-python --buildid=3noclean # produces libboost_python-3noclean.so
$ ./b2 --with-python --clean
$ ./b2 --with-python --buildid=3 # produces libboost_python-3.so

$ nm -D stage/lib/libboost_python-2.so | grep PyClass_Type
                 U PyClass_Type
$ nm -D stage/lib/libboost_python-3noclean.so | grep PyClass_Type
                 U PyClass_Type
$ nm -D stage/lib/libboost_python-3.so | grep PyClass_Type
```

As expected, `libboost_python-2.so` references the `PyClass_Type` symbol.  Additionally, the  `libboost_python-3noclean.so` contains a reference to `PyClass_Type` as it was built with `libboost_python-2.so`'s object files.  With a clean build, `libboost_python-3.so` should not contain a reference to `PyClass_Type`.

Comment: After your build, how should I modify `CmakeList.txt` for usage this libraries placed in these certain directories? Because the error is the same, after I rebuild project with including additional directories to this libraries. Nothing  was changed  in Cmake output.

Comment: I also tried to include *.so file manually: specifying path to new `libboost_python-3.so` instead of `${Boost_LIBRARIES}` in `CMakeList.txt` file: 
**target_link_libraries( hello "/home/john/soft/boost/boost_1_56_0/stage/lib/libboost_python-3.so" ${PythonLibs_LIBRARIES} )**. yield is new another error: 

**ImportError: dynamic module does not define init function (PyInit_hello)**

Comment: @IvanBereziuk The library and module names must match.  Either build the library as `mymodule.so` or name the module `hello` by using `BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(hello)`.

Comment: Yay!!! It works(in case I include `*.so` manually). But this is not the best solution to the problem (to prescribe the path to the libraries by hand). What to do when you need to use multiple boost libraries? How to integrate our library into common `${Boost_LIBRARIES}`?

Comment: Yes, I found the solution. Somehow the new boos::python3 library  have name `libboost_python-3.so`(for comparison to the old `libboost_python3.so`. So I changed `python3` on `python-3` and module began importing without errors.

Comment: @IvanBereziuk The naming difference is the result of `buildid` argument provided to `b2`.  I was using those in the example to force different versions of the library so that I could demonstrate the contaminated build.

Comment: @TannerSansbury - thank you so much almost 3 years later! your example of producing a clean build worked so much better than anything else i found online. i think a lot of sources don't differentiate between config at the bootstrap and b2 stages.

Comment: I have to remove `bin.v2/libs/python` directory in order to force making new *.so files.