# How to build and run client in python 3 in tensorflow serving

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to be able to build the client in Py3 because of some dependencies that I have. It builds fine,
but when I run the built binary, it throws an error `'undefined symbol: PyClass_Type'`. This is a type that is
only available in Py2 C, as noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25188861/libboost-python3-so-1-56-0-undefined-symbol-pyclass-type).
The  `_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so` file is automatically generated. How do I build and run the client in Py3?

```
ub64@ub64-VirtualBox:~/serving$ bazel build //tensorflow_serving/example:mnist_client --force_python=PY3
WARNING: ignoring http_proxy in environment.
WARNING: /home/ub64/.cache/bazel/_bazel_ub64/5546b242b4fa6d955b95bc3b90b5397e/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/learn/BUILD:15:1: in py_library rule @org_tensorflow//tensorflow/contrib/learn:learn: target '@org_tensorflow//tensorflow/contrib/learn:learn' depends on deprecated target '@org_tensorflow//tensorflow/contrib/session_bundle:exporter': Use SavedModel Builder instead.
WARNING: /home/ub64/.cache/bazel/_bazel_ub64/5546b242b4fa6d955b95bc3b90b5397e/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/learn/BUILD:15:1: in py_library rule @org_tensorflow//tensorflow/contrib/learn:learn: target '@org_tensorflow//tensorflow/contrib/learn:learn' depends on deprecated target '@org_tensorflow//tensorflow/contrib/session_bundle:gc': Use SavedModel instead.
INFO: Found 1 target...
Target //tensorflow_serving/example:mnist_client up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/tensorflow_serving/example/mnist_client
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.721s, Critical Path: 0.00s
ub64@ub64-VirtualBox:~/serving$ bazel-bin/tensorflow_serving/example/mnist_client
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ub64/serving/bazel-bin/tensorflow_serving/example/mnist_client.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/home/ub64/serving/bazel-bin/tensorflow_serving/example/mnist_client.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/ub64/serving/bazel-bin/tensorflow_serving/example/mnist_client.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: /home/ub64/serving/bazel-bin/tensorflow_serving/example/mnist_client.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so: undefined symbol: PyClass_Type

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ub64/serving/bazel-bin/tensorflow_serving/example/mnist_client.runfiles/tf_serving/tensorflow_serving/example/mnist_client.py", line 37, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "/home/ub64/serving/bazel-bin/tensorflow_serving/example/mnist_client.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/home/ub64/serving/bazel-bin/tensorflow_serving/example/mnist_client.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/home/ub64/serving/bazel-bin/tensorflow_serving/example/mnist_client.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 52, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ub64/serving/bazel-bin/tensorflow_serving/example/mnist_client.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/home/ub64/serving/bazel-bin/tensorflow_serving/example/mnist_client.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/ub64/serving/bazel-bin/tensorflow_serving/example/mnist_client.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 242, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: /home/ub64/serving/bazel-bin/tensorflow_serving/example/mnist_client.runfiles/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so: undefined symbol: PyClass_Type


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Settings

```
ub64@ub64-VirtualBox:~/serving$ uname -a
Linux ub64-VirtualBox 4.8.0-58-generic #63~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jun 26 18:08:51 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
ub64@ub64-VirtualBox:~/serving$ python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 17 2016, 17:05:23) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
ub64@ub64-VirtualBox:~/serving/tensorflow$ bazel version
WARNING: ignoring http_proxy in environment.
Build label: 0.5.2
```

Comment: I got the Ubuntu 16.04 tensorflow docker image, cloned the serving repo as described in github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving‌​/…, built it, and run the two commands that you have. It worked just fine. serving$ bazel-bin/tensorflow_serving/example/mnist_client   ->   please specify server host:port     serving$ python3 bazel-bin/tensorflow_serving/example/mnist_client      -> please specify server host:port

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error using python3 and installed from source.

Try to install serving by apt-get and the ModelServer by pip
https://www.tensorflow.org/serving/setup

```
pip install --upgrade tensorflow-serving-api-python3
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install tensorflow-model-server
```