# ubuntu 18.04 python3.6 failed to import PyV8 after build

Tags: python-3.6

> > > import PyV8
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >         File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/PyV8-1.0.dev0-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/PyV8.py", line 33, in 
> > >           import _PyV8
> > >       ImportError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_python-py27.so.1.58.0: undefined symbol: PyClass_Type

Comment: How can i set libboost_python-py36.so and libboost_system.so.1.65.1 when importing PyV8?

Comment: Take a look at this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/25355855/690576